# Display data from javascript variable after a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Using `express.js`, say you have the following javascript variable embedded in an `ejs` file: `<%= someVariable %>`

How would you then display the value from this variable on the same page (for example in a bootstrap modal element https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) if the actual value will be obtained from a form on the page, after the page is already loaded like so:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="someVariable" name="someVariable" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value" aria-label="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" id="search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Search</button>
</form>
```

The problem I'm running into is since the variable is undefined, until a value is entered into the form I get the following error whenever I try and load the page: `someVariable is not defined`

Is there a way to load this page even while the variable `someVariable` is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locals object holds all the ejs values you pass in. Before you use `someVariable` you can check if it is defined, with a simple if-statement:

```js
<% if (locals.someVariable) { %>
  <h1><%= someVariable %></h1>
<% } %>
```